# Disable kafka producer from properties configuration

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, configuration, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

How can a producer set up from a Kafka factory be disabled?

I started from this example from https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/
[image]

I expected that adding a property like

```
props.put("autoStartup", "false");
```

would disable the message sending, but it does not seem to work.
Running the application still sends messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no producer property like `autoStartup`, so it doesn't mean `disable the message sending`. For the producer configuration, you could see [here](https://kafka.apache.org/28/documentation.html#producerconfigs).

In Spring Kafka, `autoStartup` is used for [Listener Container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#container-auto-startup).

You could set this property by:
In `@KafkaListener`

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "myContainer", topics = "myTopic", autoStartup = "false")
```

**Or**

`**ListenerContainerFactory.setAutoStartup(Boolean autoStartup)`

Comment: So there is no solution to my question? I wanted to disable the kafka producer using properties.

Comment: Can @KafkaListener be used for producers also?

Comment: Yes, there's no property meaning `disable the kafka producer`. `@KafkaListener` is only used for consumers (`ListenerContainer`). A KafkaTemplate sends your message on demand, so if you want to stop, just don't call it.